# imagecopyresampled makes black box but not resampled image

Tags: php, resize, jpeg, resampling

I am working to resize and resample some jpeg images using PHP. It take any image greater than 500px by 500px and make the largest side 500px. This should be relatively simple but every time I run the script it makes a black jpeg. The jpeg created has the proper dimensions but does not include the resized image. The GD library is enabled, and I have made sure it is finding the original image. I've been looking at this block of code for a day and half with no luck, what am I not seeing?

```
    <?php
$testimage = 'SandyCayCaribbeanbeach.jpg';
$testfolder = "testimage/testimage.jpg";
list($orgwidth, $orgheight, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($testimage);

echo "org. width  " . $orgwidth . "px" . "<br />";
echo "org. height  " . $orgheight . "px" . "<br />";

if($orgwidth > 500 || $orgheight > 500){
    if($orgwidth > $orgheight){
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $ratio = $orgwidth/500;
        $newwidth = floor($orgwidth/$ratio);
        $newheight = floor($orgheight/$ratio);

        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($testimage);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($image_p, $testfolder, 100);
    }
    else{
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $ratio = $orgheight/500;
        $newheight = floor($orgheight/$ratio);
        $newwidth = floor($orgwidth/$ratio);

        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($testimage);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($image_p, $testfolder, 100);
    }
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly make sure you have error reporting turned on. Also make sure it can find the source image "SandyCayBaribbeanbeach.jpg".

A simple `if(file_exists())` check before handling the image resizing will help trap errors.

Comment: After turning error reporting on, it showed on line 20 my height and width variables were undefined. They were $width and $height but should have been $orgwidth and $orgheight. Thanks for the Error reporting tip, im new to this and totally forgot about it.

Comment: no problems. Error reporting will save you countless hours of frustration :) & Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had to specify a full **path** to the image, **not** a URL i.e.

/path/to/image.jpg

instead of

http://www.blah.com/image.jpg

to get this to work properly. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check to make sure your source image is truly a JPEG.  If you are running Windows, open it up in MS Paint and re-save as a JPEG.  This will help rule out the possibility of it being a different format.

Answer (score 0):

I also fought this for a while in a piece of my code recently, and found that imagecopyresampled will even return 1 if the dimensions are not defined.  Make sure that your source height and width are set.